# ¿Como puedo consultar los documentos que están comprendidos entre 2 fechas en MongoDb?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, date, mongoose

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que me retorne los documentos que estén comprendidos entre 2 fechas. Por ejemplo, quiero que la consulta me retorne los documentos comprendidos entre estas dos fechas: 2021-08-01 y 2021-08-21.

mi modelo tiene una estructura como esta:

```js
userReciver: {
  _id: 'xxxxx',
  name: 'xxxxxx'
}
tracking: {
  dateInit: "2021-08-01T05:27:25.554Z"
  dateFinish: "2021-08-21T05:27:25.554Z"

}
```

El problema al que me enfrento es que las fechas en mi base de datos están guardados en ese forma ISO que incluye también las horas, si incluyo las horas en la comparación de la consulta puede que ignore algunos documentos por una simple diferencia entre horas o segundos, cosa que no sería correcta. lo que necesito es comprar las fechas como tal, es decir, solo esta parte: 2021-08-01 .

Los parametros de consulta los recibo por la url, así que estoy amando la query de la siguiente forma:

```js
  async searchDelivery( offset, limit, query ){
    console.log(`\n\n Offset: ${offset}, Limit: ${limit}, query: ${query.deliveryStatus}`)
    let newQuery = {}, result = {};
    newQuery['$and'] = [];
    for( let property in query ){
      if( 
        property == 'run' || 
        property == 'deliveryStatus' || 
        property == 'enterpriceType'
      )
      {
        newQuery['$and'].push( { [property]: { $regex: query[property], $options: 'i' } } );
      }
      if( query.dateInit ){
          if( query.dateFinsh ){
            if( isDate ( new Date( query.dateInit ) ) ){
              if( isDate ( new Date( query.dateFinsh ) ) ){
                let compareDates = compareAsc( parseISO(req.query.dateFinish) , parseISO(req.query.dateInit) );
                if(  compareDates == -1 ){
                  result.message = 'La fecha inicial no puede ser mayor a la fecha límite.' 
                }else{
                  newQuery.push( { "tracking.dateInit": { $gte: query.dateInit, $lt: query.dateFinsh } } );
                }
              }else{
                result.message = 'La fecha limite no es válida.';
              }
            }else{
              result.message = 'La fecha Inicial no es válida.';
            }    
        }
      }
    }
    let deliveries = await deliveryModel.find( newQuery );
    
  }
```

Lo que se me había ocurrido era hacer una comparación con los operador gt y lt, pero veo que ahí me ignorará ciertos documentos solo porque no estén dentro del rango de las horas. minutos y segundos, lo que quisiera es solo comparar las fechas, es decir, solo esta parte ( 2021 - 08 -01 ), de esta forma no se ignoraría ningún documento, como podría hacerlo ?

Existe alguna forma de que pueda hacer eso dentro  de la misma consulta ? mi idea era obtener las fechas por cada modelo, extraer solo la fecha ( 2021-08-01 y 2021-08-21 ), hacer la comparación y así para cada modelo pero no creo que sea la forma correcta, he buscado en la documentación pero no he encontrado algo que me sirva. Estoy usando mongoose por si sirve de algo.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar,

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la consulta que haces actualmente? Por favor añade esa información a tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Listo, ya la agregué.

Comment: ¿Has planteado no guardar la fecha en formato texto y usar un timestamp para ello?